# What is the best practice to install IsolationForest in DataBrick platform for PySpark API?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks

I'm trying to install Isolation Forest package in DataBrick platform. The version of spark in databrick is 3.1.1:

```
print (pyspark.__version__) 
#3.1.1
```

So I tried to follow this [article](https://towardsdatascience.com/isolation-forest-and-pyspark-part-2-76f7cd9cee56) to implement `IsolationForest` but I couldn't install the package from this [repo](https://github.com/titicaca/spark-iforest#install) with following steps:

> Step 1. Package spark-iforest jar and deploy it into spark lib
>
> > cd spark-iforest/
> >
> > mvn clean package -DskipTests
> >
> > cp target/spark-iforest-.jar $SPARK_HOME/jars/

> Step 2. Package pyspark-iforest and install it via pip, skip this step if you don't need the >python pkg
>
> > cd spark-iforest/python
> >
> > python setup.py sdist
> >
> > pip install dist/pyspark-iforest-.tar.gz

So basically I run following scripts and get: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyspark_iforest'`

```py
from pyspark import SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession, functions as F
from pyspark.ml.feature import VectorAssembler, StandardScaler
from pyspark_iforest.ml.iforest import IForest, IForestModel
import tempfile

conf = SparkConf()
conf.set('spark.jars', '/full/path/to/spark-iforest-2.4.0.jar')

spark = SparkSession \
        .builder \
        .config(conf=conf) \
        .appName("IForestExample") \
        .getOrCreate()

temp_path = tempfile.mkdtemp()
iforest_path = temp_path + "/iforest"
model_path = temp_path + "/iforest_model"
```

What is the best practice to install `IsolationForest` in **DataBrick** platform for PySpark?

Answer (score 3):

This specific version of isolation forest is compiled for the [Spark 2.4 and Scala 2.11](https://github.com/titicaca/spark-iforest/blob/master/pom.xml#L15), and is binary incompatible with the Spark 3.1 that you're using.  You may try to use Databricks Runtime (DBR) versions that are based on the Spark 2.4 - 6.4 or 5.4.

You may look onto the [mmlspark](https://github.com/Azure/mmlspark) (Microsoft Machine Learning for Apache Spark) library developed by Microsoft - it has an [implementation of IsolationForest](https://mmlspark.blob.core.windows.net/docs/1.0.0-rc3/pyspark/mmlspark.isolationforest.html), although I haven't used it myself.

Answer (score 1):

You need to import the jar first before using it:

```py
from pyspark import SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession, functions as F
from pyspark.ml.feature import VectorAssembler, StandardScaler
import tempfile

conf = SparkConf()
conf.set('spark.jars', '/full/path/to/spark-iforest-2.4.0.jar')

spark = SparkSession \
        .builder \
        .config(conf=conf) \
        .appName("IForestExample") \
        .getOrCreate()


from pyspark_iforest.ml.iforest import IForest, IForestModel

temp_path = tempfile.mkdtemp()
iforest_path = temp_path + "/iforest"
model_path = temp_path + "/iforest_model"
```

I usually have the spark session created on a separate .py file or provide the `spark.jars` by using the `spark-submit` command, because the way jars are loaded sometimes give me trouble when adding them within the code only.

```py
spark-submit --jars /full/path/to/spark-iforest-2.4.0.jar my_code.py
```

Also, there is a version mismatch, as @Alex Ott mentioned but the error would be different in that case. Building IForest with pyspark 3.x is not very difficult, but if you don't want to get into it, you could downgrade the pyspark version.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I installed spark on top of the cluster in google colab [notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1DMBMlICT-iq5_i5Oz-NC5WS4eBPRdgrB?usp=sharing) to offer you kindly for quick troubleshooting. I applied your solution but still, I get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyspark_iforest'`. Would you check the notebook and run your solution for better understanding?

Comment: @Mario Thanks for providing a notebook to debug, can you take a look at your colab notebook now? I tried with both a 3.x jar and a 2.4.x jar and `from pyspark_iforest.ml.iforest import IForestModel` works. The 3.x jar is not official, I just built it some time ago locally. I didn't touch the `import mmlspark` though.

Comment: Thanks again for your quick reply/debug. I tested your [online article](https://towardsdatascience.com/isolation-forest-and-pyspark-part-2-76f7cd9cee56) when transforming all vectors to dense using a UDF, but if you check the updated notebook in the last cell, there is an error `TypeError: 'JavaPackage' object is not callable`. I noticed that you downgrade the spark to v2.4.0, but I don't see any scripts for that, except the one you edited in the first cell when installing the PySpark package, right? This helped debug it quickly and install the `pyspark_iforest` to build IsolationForest model.

Comment: @Mario this can happen for two reasons, from what I've seen: version mismatch or you need to run this with spark-submit, so I added this: `os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS'] = '--jars /content/spark-iforest-2.4.0.99.jar pyspark-shell'` in the beginning and it currently works. (with a local pre-built jar added in the data folder)